# Add comment, flag, delete links are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, hyperlinks, vote-to-delete

The add comment, flag, delete and other such links will open a popup (eg: Mod link) are broken. Clicking on them does nothing.

Javascript error console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js:16

Comment: I'm getting this, but not consistently. Refreshing the page sometimes works as does navigating away and reselecting the link to the page.

Comment: I only get the problem if I access a page via a link pointing to an answer, and not otherwise.

Comment: Happened to me a minute ago, now working fine.

Comment: Oh, I thought Its only happened to me, and notice only on few questions and found out clicking on "active" "oldest" "votes" tabs could recover from that error. I thought my chrome dev 12 browser issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now.

It took a whole lot of single-stepping through callback after callback after callback, but in the end, it was actually a bug in the HTML code.

When you link directly to an answer (instead of just a question), this answer is shown in a highlight color which then fades back to normal (as everybody has probably seen).

We're in the process of converting our pages from the old ASPX view engine to [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx), and in the process of converting the partial view that shows a single answer (this conversion happened today), there was a little too much encoding happening, so the result for the highlighted answer looked like this:

```
<div id="answer-85877" class="answer" style=&quot;background-color:#F6F5EE;&quot;>
```

This is obviously anything but valid (but it actually depends on the browser how it gets handled). When the jQuery color animation plugin tried to find the *current* color, all it found was either garbage or nothing (depending on the browser). When it found nothing, this worked fine (except that you didn't see the animation); when it found garbage, this caused the code to throw up.

Answer (score 1):

I think SO should upgrade to jQuery 1.5.2 according to error msg related to "resolveWith"

[image]

on jQuery 1.5.2 (around line 1062) (fixed following)

```
// Strange bug in FF4:
// Values changed onto the arguments object sometimes end up as undefined values
// outside the $.when method. Cloning the object into a fresh array solves the issue
deferred.resolveWith( deferred, sliceDeferred.call( args, 0 ) );
```

---

**Edit**: Its only happened on answer links, not questions.

If I commented out following line, looks like error gone.

```
$('#answer-XXXX').animate({ backgroundColor:'#FFF' }, 2000, 'linear', function() { $(this).css('background-color', ''); });
```

Comment: this error has nothing to do with resolveWith

Comment: aww, ok, but google chrome did give me that error `d.extend._Deferred.f.resolveWith` on console.

Comment: @YOU: I'll write up what happened :)

Comment: @balpha, but it is related to **$.when**?

Comment: @YOU: No -- it wasn't even a real JavaScript error.

Comment: @balpha, ok, I was just diffing codes, and noticed `$.when` is gone http://i.imgur.com/05kNW.png :-) May be just an unrelated case.

Comment: @YOU: Yeah, that's unrelated. I just removed the $.when because it was a no-op (since it received only one deferred).